# What does permutation stand for as a power?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I am just reading some books about abstract algebra and I don't understand what a permutation stands for as a power.

For example, $(1 2)^{(1 2 3 \ldots n)}=(1 3)$.

Comment: Probably conjugation : given two permutations $x,y$, one sometimes writes $x^y$ for $y^{-1}xy$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, @Oliver hit the answer. A fact you may find useful is:

> If $x$ and $y$ are two permutations of a set $\Omega$, such that $x=(\xi_1,\xi_2,...,\xi_k)$ then $$y^{-1}xy=(\xi_1^y,\xi_2^y,...,\xi_k^y)=x^y$$

Comment: You might want to also mention that you here use the convention that $a^y$ means the element that $a$ is sent to by the permutation $y$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Exactly! But what the Oliver indicated is the main conventionally accepted point. Thanks.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: May i ask you to visit the chat room? I asked a question there. Thanks so much.